# Linux does not recognize my new laptop battery

Tags: linux, linux-mint, battery

Hi there I just bought a new laptop battery for my acer 3820tg, connected it but looks like my Linux Mint 17 can not recognize it. Battery led on laptop is blinking by orange color and acpi command does not output anything...

also /sys/class/power_supply has only ADP1...

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it an Acer approved battery or 3rd party?

Comment: I would say 3rd party from AVACOM.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that your computer is set up to reject 3rd party batteries. I don't believe that it is operating system specific, so the fact that it is Linux is probably irrelevant.

Comment: I wonder if there is a BIOS setting that could be changed. On the other hand, it could also be a DOA battery.